# Como alterar URL local no IIS

Tags: aplicação-web, url, iis, windows-10, localhost

No ambiente local de desenvolvimento sempre utilizei **localhost** para acessar a aplicação, porém gostaria de utilizar URLs mais amigáveis (por exemplo: http://*analise-sistema*), tentei configurar no IIS, porém não tive êxito.
Gostaria de saber como posso estar efetuando essa configuração.

Utilizo o **Windows 10**, com o **IIS** ver. 10*.

Comment: Instalou o IIS em seu ambiente de desenvolvimento ou está utilizando o IIS Express mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abra o programa `notepad.exe` como administrador, então faça o seguinte:

1. Vá até <kbd>Arquivo</kbd> > <kbd>Abrir...</kbd>
2. Abra o caminho `[drive]:\[pasta windows]\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (na maior parte dos casos é `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

Deve abrir algo como:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Adicione isto depois de `#  ::1             localhost`:

```
#   ::1             localhost
   127.0.0.1       analise-sistema
```

Salve o documento.

> **Nota:** Uma coisa importante, as vezes o antivirus bloqueia a edição do arquivo `hosts`, por isso é necessário desativar ele enquanto estiver editando e ativo-lo novamente logo após salvar o seu documento.